# Visual Studio Online - The type or namespace name yyy does not exist in the namespace xxx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have a solution from Visual Studio 2015, using the .NET Framework 4.6. Locally, I can compile without any problem and I am using NuGet in its latest version (3.1).

When I check-in and then build using Visual Studio Online, I get errors like this:

> - Plumbing\DALContainerRegistration.cs (1): The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you
>     missing an assembly reference?)
> - Storage\BlobStorage.cs (5): The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you
>     missing an assembly reference?)

I understand that I am missing these references on the Build server, but I don't see how I can resolve this. In the two examples above, I get the Enterprise library and Azure storage library from NuGet, so there is apparently no reason why it would not work.

I have a NuGet.config at the root of my sln and here is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong? If you need any other info, please let me know.

Comment: What is your target build framework?

Comment: Have you enabled the Package Restore options in the solution?  Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings.  Once the  dialog opens, expand NuGet Package Manager.  In the General tab, ensure `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` are checked.

Comment: @bowlturner: .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: @SwDevMan81: Yes these options are enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by modifying the NuGet.config file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="nuget.orgv3" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `Restore NuGet Packages`. In VSO Build vNext you can do this in the Build step. [image]

To create a new build definition:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Lukkha Coder, how can I get access to this UI?

Comment: https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/OE/ENG/_build#templateId=vsBuild&_a=simple-process
Replace xxx with your url.

Comment: I'm afraid it does not work, I also replaced OE with my collection name... Do I have to create a new collection? My collection has been created before vNext was released, in April...

Comment: You do not. However you need to check if your build is using the old Xaml TeamBuild or the new VSO Build vNext.

Comment: Ok Lukkha, I could find where to access these options in my current project, I simply had to create a new build from the VSO portal. So I tried this new Build, and unfortunately I still have errors:

`Unable to find version '5.0.505.0' of package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Caching'.
Unable to find version '5.0.505.0' of package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Cryptography'.
Unable to find version '6.0.1304.0' of package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common'.
Unable to find version '6.0.1304.0' of package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Logging'.
Unable to find version '5.6.2' of package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm'.`